# What is 2nd level cache?

Tags: orm, telerik

We have to use Telerik ORM for our project. As i was reading its features it boasts too much about its 2nd level cache feature. Can anybody explain me what is it?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: try the telerik forums. or google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the ability to cache the data of the result of a query outside of the DataContext/UoW/Session (what ever telerik decided to call it). So any queries after the initial one will return cached data.

Same as using the application cache or memcache etc.

Edit:

A google for "Telerik Second Level Cache" returned:

http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/2nd-level-cache.html

Answer (score 0):

If it's anything like NHibernate's 2nd level cache it means query caching.